# Form Download data OnStart() or OnAppearing()

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin-forms-4

In my Xamain Forms app i need to download a json file for populate listviews.
I check first if internet is ok then download json file with an animate page.

I put in app.cs

```
  public App()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new AnimatePage());
            }

    protected override async void OnStart()
            {
                var isConnected = await CheckForInternetConnectionAsync();
                if (isConnected)
                {
                     await DownloadjsonAsync();                
             }
                else
                {
                    //internet down
                }
            }
        private static async Task<bool> CheckForInternetConnectionAsync()
        {
            using (var tokSource = new CancellationTokenSource(5000))
            {
                try
                {
                    await _httpClient.GetAsync("http://google.com/generate_204", tokSource.Token);
                }
                catch (OperationCanceledException)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                    return false;

                }
            }
            return true;
        }
private static async Task<bool> DownloadjsonAsync()
        {
            using (var tokSource = new CancellationTokenSource(5000))
            {
                try
                {
                    

                    var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync("http://url/file.json", tokSource.Token);
                    using (var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
                    {
                        var localFolder = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
                        var newpath = Path.Combine(localFolder, "milka.json");
                        var fileInfo = new FileInfo(newpath);
                        using (var fileStream = fileInfo.OpenWrite())
                        {
                            await stream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (OperationCanceledException)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                    return false;

                }
            }
            return true;
        }
```

in AnimatePage :

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
           base.OnAppearing();
           label.Text = "Loading ....";
            
          await Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());
        }
```

Is it good to doing this on OnStart or better to do in Ui OnAppearing()?
I have just doing like this for start downloading as sonn as possible but how i know in AnimaPage file is downloaded and open mainPage?

Comment: I would do it in AnimatePage OnAppearing() it makes it more clean on what should happen. Now in the App() constructor you've already set MainPage and that will run OnAppearing() in that page around same time as OnStart() methond of the App. They are started by 2 different threads.

Comment: If there is only something like one second difference it will be more easy to do everything OnAppearing() :)